# Node.js pkg - how to execute a command line script

Tags: node.js

We use node.js to build our code which accesses 2 dynamic configuration files during runtime and calls a shell script to perform some actions.

We also use the node package "pkg" to generate executable.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg

With the pkg generated executable, if the command line to execute the script is hardcoded, then it works. However, if we pass the command and its parameters into a variable first, then it doesn't work with "command not found".

Example: 
Working: `child_process.exec("/bin/sh helloWorld");`

Not Working:

```
let cmd = "/bin/sh helloWorld";
child_process.exec(cmd);
```

> Error: /bin/sh: undefined: command not found

Any idea about solving this? We would like to pass in some parameters for the command script instead of hardcode it.

Best regards,
Autorun

Answer (score 0):

I know this is kind of late, but have you tried using a template litiral like

```
let options = 'PUT_YOUR_OPTIONS_HERE'
child_process.exec(`/bin/sh helloworld ${options})
```